# PHPmyadmin and Wordpress directories access denied

Tags: apache, permissions, centos7

Running wordpress locally on a centOS 7 server running the latest apache, PHPmyadmin and mariadb-server.

IP/wordpress and IP/phpmyadmin on systems within the local network yields "403 forbidden" "you dont have permission to access (directory) on this server."

How can I fix this to allow the website to be seen on the public internet?

Comment: 1) try to change ownership to apache chown apache:apache /var/www/html/yourfolder 2) check if it is an selinux issue by trying to setenforce 0 (most likely scenario). If it is, you will have to set context with semanage

Answer (score 1):

Could be a lot of things.

In your main Apache configuration file (e.g. /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf on Arch Linux), confirm your `DocumentRoot` path. The files you want to serve must reside there, or in sub-directories from there (If not, you might want to use an `Alias` to specify another path). Since you call IP/wordpress and IP/phpmyadmin, then you probably have directories called *wordpress* and *phpmyadmin* under your DocumentRoot path.

You also want to check the `Directory` groups in your Apache configuration file. Under those, the main culprit would be the `Require` directive set to `all denied` or something else too much restrictive like `ip` `your_ip`.

Finally, PHP can restrict path access with the `open_basedir` directive. Look for it in your php configuration file (e.g. /etc/php/php.ini on Arch Linux). If the line is commented, you're fine. But if a path is specified, your wordpress and phpmyadmin files must reside there.

Depending on your setup, any directive mentioned above could be in another Apache configuration file (e.g. /etc/httpd/conf/extra/* on Arch Linux).

Take a look at Apache and PHP online documentation for information about those directives.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an issue with your directory privileges.

Use the follwing command to check it:

```
cd your_site_directory     
ls -l
```

You can have a look to have a better understanding on directory privileges [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php).

As mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/416236/what-is-centos-5s-apache-user-group) apache runs under "apache" user.
Have a look at this post [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) to fix the issue.
All files should belong at least to apache group. To do it you can use

```
cd your_site_directory
chgrp -R apache ./*
```

Comment: what exact directory should I be working on here? just the wordpress directory? I'm new to this and all directories are default if that helps you explain things any better.

Comment: If you din't perform any change on your virtual hosts it should be on /var/www/html.  Have a look at this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-7

Comment: Try this line here:

`sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/*`

I took it form the link above

Comment: This might help too https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-a-centos-6-4-vps#step-five-—-see-the-results!

Comment: This too https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6